¿porque no se ejecuta esta linea if 'Video unavailable. This video is not available'?
Hola a todos lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un programa para que baje musica desde youtube con ffmpeg, pero no logro que se salte el error Video unavailable. This video is not available, estoy usando python, y no se como se le puede hacer.
Quiero que el codigo se salte los videos que esten no disponibles o que esten en privados de cualquier lista de videos de youtube, lo que quiero es descargar musica desde youtube con ffmpeg y un script en python con un archivo json para poder guardar el progreso de los archivos y asi no tenga que estar descargando los mismo archivos mp3 de nuevo, sino que pueda descargar los archivos que no esten registrados en la ruta en la que se guardan las canciones, he investigado en google pero no hay nada, o todavia no se como buscar bien en google, pero ya llevo 2 días con este error, aclaro apenas estoy dandome la libertad de poder hacer codigo, por lo que todavia uso chat gpt para poder aprender, no me tiren arena, lo que pasa es que ya intente con chat gpt y con notion ia y no me da el codigo que ocupo, siempre se queda en el error ERROR: [youtube] raQnt44smdQ: Video unavailable. This video is not available
Error al descargar el video: ERROR: [youtube] raQnt44smdQ: Video unavailable. This video is not available, de antemano les agradezco si me ayudan por favor, el error esta en estas lineas del codigo:
error_message = str(e).lower()
            if 'Video unavailable. This video is not available' in error_message or 'this video is not available' in error_message or 'Video unavailable' in error_message:
                messagebox.showinfo("Video no disponible", f'Video no disponible: {video_info["webpage_url"]}. Saltando al siguiente video...')
                return False

no se ejecuta el if sino que se lo salta y me deja con el error que el archivo no esta disponible, ya actualice yt-dlp, y no se salta los videos que no estan disponibles, estoy descargando una lista de canciones en youtube, pero cuando llego a la canción 14 me sale error y no sigue avanzando el programa.
    el codigo completo es este:
    
    import yt_dlp
    import os
    import json
    from tkinter import filedialog, Tk, Button, Label, Entry, messagebox
    from threading import Thread, Event
    import time
    
    # Evento para pausar/reanudar descarga
    pause_event = Event()
    
    # Cargar videos ya descargados previamente
    def load_progress():
        try:
            with open('download_progress.json', 'r') as f:
                return set(json.load(f))
        except (FileNotFoundError, json.JSONDecodeError):
            return set()
    
    # Guardar el progreso de los videos descargados
    def save_progress(downloaded_videos):
        with open('download_progress.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(list(downloaded_videos), f)
    
    # Función para generar nombres únicos para títulos desconocidos
    def get_unique_filename(base_name, extension, output_folder):
        counter = 1
        unique_name = f"{base_name} {counter}.{extension}"
        while os.path.exists(os.path.join(output_folder, unique_name)):
            counter += 1
            unique_name = f"{base_name} {counter}.{extension}"
        return unique_name
    
    # Descargar un video con control de pausa/reanudación y manejo de errores
    def download_video(video_info, output_folder, downloaded_videos, max_retries=20, retry_delay=5):
        ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'outtmpl': os.path.join(output_folder, '%(title)s.%(ext)s'),
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                'preferredquality': '192',
            }],
            'noplaylist': True,
            'socket_timeout': 2000,
            'ignoreerrors': True,
            'ffmpeg_location': 'C:/Users/jorge/Downloads/ffmpeg-2024-09-22-git-a577d313b2-essentials_build/bin/ffmpeg',  # Asegúrate de poner la ruta correcta a FFmpeg
        }
        attempt = 0
        while attempt < max_retries:
            try:
                with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                    video_title = video_info.get('title', None)
                    video_id = video_info.get('id')
                    
                    if video_id in downloaded_videos:
                        print(f'Saltando {video_title if video_title else "Unknown Title"}, ya está descargado.')
                        return False
    
                    if video_title is None:
                        video_title = get_unique_filename("Unknown Title", "mp3", output_folder)
                    
                    print(f'Intentando descargar {video_title}... (Intento {attempt + 1})')
                    pause_event.wait()  # Pausar si el evento está activo
                    
                    # Usar extract_info en lugar de download para manejar mejor los errores
                    info = ydl.extract_info(video_info['webpage_url'], download=False)
                    
                    if info is None or 'entries' in info:
                        messagebox.showinfo("Video no disponible", f'Video no disponible o es una playlist: {video_info["webpage_url"]}. Saltando...')
                        return False
                    
                    # Si llegamos aquí, el video está disponible, así que lo descargamos
                    ydl.download([video_info['webpage_url']])
                    downloaded_videos.add(video_id)
                    return True  # Descarga completada
            except yt_dlp.DownloadError as e:
                error_message = str(e).lower()
                if 'Video unavailable. This video is not available' in error_message or 'this video is not available' in error_message or 'Video unavailable' in error_message:
                    messagebox.showinfo("Video no disponible", f'Video no disponible: {video_info["webpage_url"]}. Saltando al siguiente video...')
                    return False
                print(f'Error en el intento {attempt + 1}: {e}')
                if attempt + 1 < max_retries:
                    print(f'Reintentando en {retry_delay} segundos...')
                    time.sleep(retry_delay)
                else:
                    print(f'No se pudo descargar el video {video_info["webpage_url"]} después de {max_retries} intentos.')
                    return False
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error inesperado al descargar {video_info['webpage_url']}: {e}")
                return False
            attempt += 1
        return False
    
    
    # Función para seleccionar carpeta de descarga
    def choose_folder():
        folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
        return folder_selected
    
    # Función para iniciar la descarga en un hilo
    def start_download(url, output_folder):
        downloaded_videos = load_progress()
        unavailable_videos = 0
        with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL() as ydl:
            try:
                playlist_info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
                if 'entries' in playlist_info:  # Es una playlist
                    total_videos = len(playlist_info['entries'])
                    for index, video_info in enumerate(playlist_info['entries'], 1):
                        if not video_info:  # Si la entrada de video está vacía, pasar al siguiente
                            continue
                        pause_event.wait()  # Pausar si está activo
                        print(f"Intentando descargar video {index} de {total_videos}")
                        video_downloaded = download_video(video_info, output_folder, downloaded_videos)
                        if video_downloaded:
                            save_progress(downloaded_videos)
                        else:
                            unavailable_videos += 1
                            print(f"No se pudo descargar el video {index}. Continuando con el siguiente...")
                else:  # Es un solo video
                    video_downloaded = download_video(playlist_info, output_folder, downloaded_videos)
                    if video_downloaded:
                        save_progress(downloaded_videos)
                    else:
                        unavailable_videos += 1
                
                print(f"Descarga completada. {unavailable_videos} videos no estaban disponibles.")
            except yt_dlp.DownloadError as e:
                print(f"Error al descargar el video: {e}")
                messagebox.showerror("Error", f"No se pudo descargar el video: {e}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error inesperado: {e}")
                messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Ha ocurrido un error inesperado: {e}")
    
    # Función para mostrar la interfaz gráfica
    def create_gui():
        root = Tk()
        root.title("Descargador de YouTube")
        
        url_label = Label(root, text="Introduce la URL del video o playlist:")
        url_label.pack()
        
        url_entry = Entry(root, width=50)
        url_entry.pack()
        
        # Variables de control
        global pause_event
        pause_event.set()  # Iniciar descarga habilitada
        
        def iniciar_descarga():
            url = url_entry.get()
            folder = choose_folder()
            if not folder:
                messagebox.showwarning("Carpeta no seleccionada", "Por favor, selecciona una carpeta.")
                return
            # Iniciar la descarga en un hilo
            download_thread = Thread(target=start_download, args=(url, folder))
            download_thread.start()
        
        def pausar_descarga():
            if pause_event.is_set():
                pause_event.clear()  # Pausar descarga
                print("Descarga pausada.")
            else:
                print("La descarga ya está pausada.")
        
        def reanudar_descarga():
            if not pause_event.is_set():
                pause_event.set()  # Reanudar descarga
                print("Descarga reanudada.")
            else:
                print("La descarga ya está en curso.")
        
        # Botones para la interfaz
        download_button = Button(root, text="Iniciar descarga", command=iniciar_descarga)
        download_button.pack()
        
        pause_button = Button(root, text="Pausar descarga", command=pausar_descarga)
        pause_button.pack()
        
        resume_button = Button(root, text="Reanudar descarga", command=reanudar_descarga)
        resume_button.pack()
        
        root.mainloop()
    
    # Ejecutar el programa principal
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        create_gui()


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! No se entiende cual es el problema... o sea en donde de todo ese codigo esta tu problema???

Pero sigo sin entender el problema.. cual es el problema.. el video existe y a vos te figura que no???

hay videos que estan privados o no estan disponibles y quiero que se los salte para poder descargar solo los videos que estan en publico

perfecto, si estas agarrando el error, pasas de largo.. tu problema es que no sabes como seguir cuando sale el error? o sea.. no entendes que hace tu codigo, no??? ahi tenes un return, que implica que vuelve a quien lo llamo.. vos queres eso???

El problema en realidad es bastante simple y lo estás causando en:
ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    ...,
    'ignoreerrors': True,       # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    'ffmpeg_location': ...
}

De forma explícita le estás indicando a yt_dlp que no genere excepciones cuando se produzca un error en la descarga o pos-procesado del vídeo. En este caso, simplemente pone el mensaje en StdError sin lanzar una excepción, por lo que tus bloques try-except no capturan nada, el except no se ejecuta y con ello tampoco el condicional.
Un ejemplo simplificado:
import yt_dlp


URLS = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_fffffffff']

ydl_opts = {
    'ignoreerrors': True,
}

with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    try:
        ydl.download(URLS)
    except yt_dlp.DownloadError as e:
        print(f"Se produjo un error: {e}")

Esto genera la siguiente salida:
[youtube] Extracting URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_fffffffff
[youtube] f_fffffffff: Downloading webpage
[youtube] f_fffffffff: Downloading ios player API JSON
[youtube] f_fffffffff: Downloading web creator player API JSON
ERROR: [youtube] f_fffffffff: Video unavailable

Como ves, imprime un mensaje en stderror, pero nuestro print en el except no aparece por ningún lado porque no se genera ninguna excepción.
En cambio con:
ydl_opts = {
    'ignoreerrors': False,
}

tenemos:
[youtube] Extracting URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_fffffffff
[youtube] f_fffffffff: Downloading webpage
[youtube] f_fffffffff: Downloading ios player API JSON
[youtube] f_fffffffff: Downloading web creator player API JSON
ERROR: [youtube] f_fffffffff: Video unavailable
Se produjo un error: ERROR: [youtube] f_fffffffff: Video unavailable  # <<<<<<<<

En definitiva, o bien dejas de ignorar los errores y manejas todas las excepciones o bien capturas los errores mediante otra vía, lo más simple mediante logging:
import yt_dlp

URLS = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_fffffffff']

class MyLogger:
    def debug(self, msg):
        if msg.startswith('[debug] '):
            pass
        else:
            self.info(msg)

    def info(self, msg):
        pass

    def warning(self, msg):
        pass

    def error(self, msg):
        print(f"Se produjo un error: {msg}")  # <<<<<<<<<


ydl_opts = {
    'logger': MyLogger(),                     # <<<<<<<<
    'ignoreerrors': True,
}

with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(URLS)


¡Bien hecho, miraste la raíz del problema!

Primero, la condición se puede registrar más fácilmente usando el módulo re:
import re

# if re.search('unavailable|is not available', str(e), flags=re.I):
if re.search('Video unavailable|This video is not available', str(e), flags=re.I):
    messagebox.showinfo(
        "Video no disponible",
        f'Video no disponible: {video_info["webpage_url"]}. '
        'Saltando al siguiente video...'
        )
    return False
else:
    print(f'Error en el intento {attempt + 1}: {e}')

En segundo lugar, si la condición no se activa, proporcione (muéstrenos)  la salida a la consola, que ocurre en el bloque else (para que haya una oportunidad de ayudarlo).

O su opción de términos:
error_message = str(e).lower()  # Aquí has llevado a minúsculas, ¡sé consistente!
if ('video unavailable. this video is not available' in error_message
        or 'video unavailable' in error_message
        or 'this video is not available' in error_message):
    messagebox.showinfo(
        "Video no disponible",
        f'Video no disponible: {video_info["webpage_url"]}. '
        'Saltando al siguiente video...'
        )
    return False

